# xCode7 how to access "energy gauge"?

Tags: ios, ios8, profiling, xcode7, energy

I'm looking at a list of new features of xCode7 and see that there's a [new "energy gauge" tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html). However, I don't see energy gauge in the debug session side panel (xCode Version 7.0 beta 5 (7A176x), deployed on iOS 8.4.1 device):

[image]

I'm expecting to see something like this:

[image]

I tried debugging with instruments, but get a report with an "energy level out of 20", and see nothing that resembles this kind of energy gauge. **How can I see energy consumption of an app in xCode7?** Does this require iOS9 installed on device?

Comment: did u found the answer?

Comment: @AhdRadwan (and any future people) you need to launch the app from Xcode to a device and (keep it attached) in order to see the Energy Impact place in Xcode